# Preventing multiple View clicks in Android (MonoDroid) using C# lock()

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, xamarin.android, synchronization

I'm trying to prevent multiple clicks from taking affect, and would like to know if the following logic will cover all possibilities?

Currently, each successive "click" (touch) fires off an additional download.

```
private object CLICK_LOCK = new System.Object();

public void ViewClickHandler(object o, System.EventArgs a)
{
    View clickedView = (View)o;

    lock (CLICK_LOCK)
    {
        if (clickedView.Clickable == false)
        {
            return;
        }

        clickedView.Clickable = false;
    }

    // sets clickedView.Clickable = true when finished
    (new DownloadAsyncTask()).Execute();
}
```

Comment: You mean you want to prevent multiple View Clicks in a short time ?

Comment: @YorkShen By either accidental twitches or impatience, yeah.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent multiple View clicks in a short time, a better solution is set a limit time for the Button. If the time interval between the two clicks does not exceed the `MIN_CLICK_DELAY_TIME`, the event will not trigger.

```
//Prevent multiple clicks in 1 second.
public static int MIN_CLICK_DELAY_TIME = 1000;
private long lastClickTime = 0;

bt.Click += ViewClickHandler;

public void ViewClickHandler(object o, System.EventArgs a)
{
    long currentTime = Calendar.Instance.TimeInMillis;
    if (currentTime - lastClickTime > MIN_CLICK_DELAY_TIME)
    {
         lastClickTime = currentTime;
         OnNoDoubleClick();
    }
}

protected void OnNoDoubleClick()
{
    (new DownloadAsyncTask()).Execute();
}
```

Comment: This moves the race condition from `clickedView.Clickable` to `lastClickTime`, which would then need the lock to ensure mutual exclusion. I'll test this out anyway, thanks.

Comment: If this does require a lock, then it would have to be around the entire **`if`** block, `lock(){ if(){...}}`, since `OnNoDoubleClick` is potentially complex it's got a higher probability of throwing an exception, something that should never be done from within a lock.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix/

Comment: Thanks, I will check it.